# Writing multiple files to S3 as a backup and dealing with eventual consistency

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to use S3 to store a set of files corresponding to a RocksDB backup. Considering that S3 is eventually consistent, can all the files be read in their entirety almost right after storing them in S3. The sequence I am referring to is

```
T1: Take RocksDB backup (generates a bunch of files in a folder)
T2: Use S3 TransferManager or aws s3 sync to upload this folder to S3.
T3: Use S3 TransferManager or aws s3 sync to download this folder from S3.
```

If the time gap between T3 and T2 is very less, is it possible that some files in S3 are not visible at T3 due to eventual consistency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New files should be immediately visible, since S3 uses read-after-write consistency for new files. Eventual consistency is only used when you are updating existing files. The details (including a caveat for read-after-write consistency) are found here: [Amazon S3 data consistency model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel)